# What is the difference between a resource file and a satellite DLL?

Tags: .net, satellite-assembly

I am not getting the difference between resource files and satellite dll.

Answer (score 4):

Ressource files usually get compiled into the application. A satellite dll is a dll, that includes all the ressources of an application and in addition, through its special nomenclature can be loaded based on the country schema, that is regional settings.

```
409 : LocaleID for English (United States)
40C : LocaleID for French (Standard)
```

When I name my dll testSAT40C.dll, it will be loaded when I'm working when selecting regional settings for France.

You can then get ressoirces using

```
     If (LoadLocalizedResources) Then

        ' Pull a string resource out of a local resource
        ' object for demonstration purposes.
        Command1.Caption = GetString(101)
     End If
```

For a complete example (including the code for the functions GetString and LoadLocalizedResources) look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188659). (I know the sample is in VB6, but easy enough to port to other languages.)

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar, Satelite Dlls are for *Translated* resources.

Comment: Actually, I just looked and there are a lot of similar questions on this, you might like to delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Satellite DLLs are useful for storing resource files, such as icons, bitmaps, and resource strings, in a centralized location for use in add-ins and other applications. Resources file will converted to satellite DLL when building the application. Satellite DLLs can be reuse in other application.Satellite DLLs are famous for localization. you can create different resource files for different languages, convert to Satellite DLLs and reuse in different applications where you need localization.